# adding LINQ tool from "code tools" but it is not reflecting in Add new items from Solution

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.android, linq-to-sql

I am trying to build an APP in xamarin bu i am facing a simple yet critical problem.

I am adding LINQ tool from "code tools" but it is not reflecting in Add new items from Solution

Linq installed_codetool

[image: 1]

linq_notshowing_NewItem_Solution

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

LiNQ to SQL is a .NET Framework only technology. Use EF Core or plain ADO.NET instead